# Trouble getting SonarQube to analyze non-maven java project

Tags: java, hudson, sonarqube

I am trying to build and run an analyses on a **non-maven java project** by building it on Hudson and then running a Sonar analyses via the Hudson-Sonar-plugin.

The trouble is, Sonar assumes that the project is a maven project, and fails the build when it doesn't find a pom file.

How can I fix this?

Here's the relevant parts from the stack trace from Hudson:

```
[workspace] $ mvn.bat -f D:\Hudson\jobs\BirdApp\workspace\pom.xml -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://orbuild01:9000 ******** ********
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-readable POM D:\Hudson\jobs\BirdApp\workspace\pom.xml: D:\Hudson\jobs\BirdApp\workspace\pom.xml (The system cannot find the file specified) @ 

    .........
Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: BirdApp #8 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am not sure what other information you might need in my question, but let me know in a comment and I'll add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For non-Maven Java projects, you have to use the dedicated Sonar analysis build step, which relies on the standalone SonarQube Runner.